# How can I join selected columns of multiple csv files into one data frame? Jupyter

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I am slightly confused because the following seems to work:

```
raw_data_df = pd.DataFrame()


temp = pd.read_csv('/Users/bob/desktop/Research_data/tobii/42r-export.csv', sep = ',', encoding = 'latin-1')
raw_data_df['1'] = temp['Gaze point X']
raw_data_df['2'] = temp['Gaze point Y']
```

However the following does not work:

```
for i in files:
  temp = pd.read_csv(path + i , sep = ',', encoding = 'latin-1')
  print(temp['Gaze point X'])
  raw_data_df[i+"x"] = temp['Gaze point X']
  raw_data_df[i+"y"] = temp['Gaze point Y']
```

where files is

```
path = "/Users/bob/desktop/Research_data/tobii/"
files = [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path,f))]
```

Instead of returning a pandas data frame where column names are i+"x" or  i+"y" i get a list of lists.

here is a sample of what is outputted with raw_data_df

```
132660     857
132661     846
Name: Gaze point X, Length: 132662, dtype: int64
0      1206
1      1204
2      1205
3      1205
```

How can I join selected columns of multiple csv files into one data frame?

Comment: What becomes a list of lists?

Comment: I return the data frame and it is in some sort of list of all the columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's any need to initialise an empty dataframe. You can iterate over your files, load only the columns you need (using `usecols`), and then concatenate all dataframes at the end.

Furthermore, when concatenating path artifacts, use `os.path.join`.

```
import os

cols = ['Gaze point X', 'Gaze point Y']

df_list = []
for f in files:
    temp = pd.read_csv(
         os.path.join(path, f), sep=',', encoding='latin-1', usecols=cols
    )
    temp.columns = [f + i for i in ['x', 'y']]
    df_list.append(temp)
```

Now, just concatenate the dataframes with `pd.concat`.

```
df = pd.concat(df_list, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry there was a ds.store file inside the files I was searching that was throughing everything off. I just deleted it and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Building on [@COLDSPEED's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48677044/9209546), you could use a list comprehension:

```
def rename_cols(df, f):
    df.columns = [f + i for i in ['x', 'y']]
    return df

df = pd.concat([rename_cols(pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, f),
                sep=',', encoding='latin-1', usecols=cols), f) for f in files],
                ignore_index=True)
```